# Splitting a complex controur integration in two. Figuring out the orientation.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Say I have an integration

$$\int_{L_1} f(z)dz $$

that I want to write as a sum of

$$\int_{L_2} f(z)dz \quad and \quad \int_{L_3} f(z)dz $$

[image]

$L_1,L_2$ are positively oriented. Suppose $L_3$ be defined as positively too:

If all contours are positively oriented do I get this:

$$\int_{L_2} f(z)dz  + \int_{L_3} f(z)dz $$

or this:

$$\int_{L_2} f(z)dz  -  \int_{L_3} f(z)dz $$

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{L_1} f(z)dz =\int_{L_2} f(z)dz+\int_{L_3} f(z)dz $$
Because you have to keep the order of visit of the points on $L_1$.

Note that the segment you had (splitting the figure in two) is visited in both orientation and therefore is not counted.